# OR operation with postgREST API

Tags: postgrest

Consider I have two columns using which I want to fetch the rows. The condition would be

> WHERE column1="test" OR column2="test"

How do I achieve this with postgREST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request would be:

```
GET /table?or=(column1.eq.test,column2.eq.test) HTTP/1.1
```

The recently added [Logical Operators](https://postgrest.org/en/latest/api.html#logical-operators) section in the docs has a more practical example.